# If $f: [a,b] \rightarrow [c,d]$ is a continuous bijection and $f(a)<f(b)$ then prove that for all $a<x<b$, then $f(a)<f(x)<f(b)$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am having trouble proving this problem.  If $f: [a,b] \rightarrow [c,d]$ is a continuous bijection and $f(a)<f(b)$ then prove that for all $a<x<b$, then $f(a)<f(x)<f(b)$.  I was told that I should use a contradiction, then the Intermediate Value Theorem.  I decided to rewrite $f(a)<f(x)<f(b)$ as the statement $f(a)<f(x)$ and $f(x)<f(b)$.  When I use proof by contradiction, I then have the statement if $a<x<b$ then $f(a) \geq f(x)$ or $f(x) \geq f(b)$.  I am not sure what I should do next in order to use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 4):

If there is some $x\in (a,b)$ with $f(x)\geq f(b)$, then by the intermediate value theorem there exists $a<y\leq x$ such that $f(y)=b$. This contradicts the fact that $f$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a<x<b, f(x)\leq f(a)$, since $f$ is continuous, $f([x,b])$ is an interval, thus there exists $y\in [x,b]$ such that $f(y)=f(a)$ contradiction since $f$ is bijective.

Similar method if $f(x)\geq f(b)$ with $[a,x]$

Answer (score 0):

We have (i) $f$ is continuous, (ii) continuous functions map connected sets to connected sets and (iii) the connected subsets of the real line are the intervals.

Hence $f$ maps intervals into intervals. Since $f$ is a bijection (injection is
sufficient), it maps disjoint intervals into disjoint intervals.

Since $[a,x)$ and $(x,b]$ are disjoint intervals, so are $f([a,x))$ and
$f((x,b])$.
Since $f(a)<f(b)$ and $f([a,b]) = f([a,x)) \cup f(\{x\}) \cup f((x,b])$, 
we must have $f(a)< f(x) < f(b)$.